# How to execute long running/polling operations in Eclipse Vert.x

Tags: microservices, vert.x

I have a scenario where we need to keep on polling a database table for all active users and perform an api call to fetch any unread emails from their inbox. My approach is to use two verticles, one for polling and another for fetching emails for an user. The first verticle when found an user, sends a message(userId) to the second verticle through an event bus to fetch emails. That way, I can increase the number of second verticle instances required when there are lots of users.

Following two ways I found I can use to poll the database for active users and then perform an api call for each user.

1. vertx.setPeriodic
2. vertx.executeBlocking

But in the manual, its mentioned that for long running/polling tasks, its better to create an application managed thread to handle the task.

Is my approach for the problem correct, or is there a better approach to solve the problem at hand? 
If I go through an application managed thread, can you please help illustrate with an example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dedicated worker thread pool for that, and run your periodic tasks on it:

```
public class PeriodicWorkerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();

        vertx.deployVerticle(new MyPeriodicWorker(), new DeploymentOptions()
                .setWorker(true)
                .setWorkerPoolSize(1)
                .setWorkerPoolName("periodic"));

    }
}

class MyPeriodicWorker extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start() {
        vertx.setPeriodic(1000, (r) -> {
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
    }
}
```